# Example of Differentiable everywhere but not satisfy Second Fundamental Thm of Calculus

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I have been having an argument with my friend. My friend claims that the following statement is true.

> Let $a<b$ be real numbers. Suppose that there is a function
>   $F:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which is a function such that it is
>   differentiable everywhere, i.e., there is a function
>   $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=F'(x)$ for all $x\in
> [a,b]$. Then it is true that
>
> \begin{equation}
> \displaystyle\int_{a}^b f(x)\,dx = F(b)-F(a).
> \end{equation}
>
> Here $f$ is assumed to be integrable, in whatever integrals.

I've been trying to disprove this statement. He convinces me by using a result in Tao's Analysis I that this is true in the case of Riemann integrable $f$. However, that does not imply that this statement is still true if $f$ is just Lebesgue integrable. I've been searching for a function that is differentiable everywhere, but its derivative does not satisfy the above equation.

My idea is to use an example of a function $F$ which is differentiable everywhere on $[a,b]$, but not absolutely continuous. This implies that it does not satisfy the above equation. My only problem is, this (desired) conclusion is too strong. We can infer only that

> $f$ is not Lebesgue integrable or not satisfy the equation.

while my desired conclusion is

> $f$ is Lebesgue integrable, but not satisfy the equation.

Can anyone suggest me a function $F$ which is differentiable everywhere (on a compact interval) such that its derivative is Lebesgue integrable, but not satisfy the above equation?

Edited : Fixed some confusion when I first typed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the statement your friend claims is true. According to this page, (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus)

I quote from that page: If a real function $F$ on $[a, b]$ admits a derivative $f(x)$ at every point $x$ of $[a, b]$ and if this derivative $f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[a, b]$, then
$$
\int_a^b f(t) dt = F(b) - F(a)
$$
The Wikipedia page cites Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis* for this result.

Comment: Oops, my bad. How did I overlook that statement. Okay, I will read that again.